# Discrete Sobolev embedding

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

It is true in one dimension that $H^1$ is continuously embedded in $L^{\infty}.$

Now, consider a compact interval $[0,1]$ with a partition $I_n:=([m/n,(m+1)/n])_{m \in \left\{0,...,n-1 \right\}}$ and a function $f$ on  $I_n$ that is constant on every interval $[m/n,(m+1)/n].$

Then we can define the discrete derivative $f'(x)=n\left(\tfrac{f\left(\tfrac{x+1}{n}\right)-f\left(\tfrac{x-1}{n}\right)}{2}\right)$ and modify it accordingly on the boundary of the partition.

If we then define the $H^1_n$ norm on the space of such functions $$\Vert f \Vert _{H^1_n} := \sqrt{ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\left\Vert f\left( \frac{i}{n} \right) \right\Vert^2 +\left\Vert f'\left( \frac{i}{n} \right) \right\Vert^2\right) },$$

it is obvious that $H^1_n$ embeds of course continuously into $L^{\infty}.$

However, I am wondering whether $\Vert f \Vert_{L^{\infty}} \le C \Vert f \Vert_{H^1_n}$ holds for a constant independent of $n$ and $f$? This is to say, is this a discrete approximation of the Sobolev embedding theorem?

Comment: You probably meant $2/n$ instead of $2n$ in the denominator in the definition of the discrete derivative. Is your constant allowed to depend on $f$? If not there is no such constant (consider the function which is 1 on one interval and zero on all others).

Comment: @user35593 no, the constant must not depend on $f$ but in this case, the $H^1_n$ norm would blow up as well, no? Because of the derivative.

Comment: I think this works, and it should in fact become obvious when you switch to the more natural convention of interpolating the $n$ values of an element $f\in H^1_n$ linearly (rather than make the function piecewise constant). Then your discrete derivative is the actual derivative, and you're just computing the conventional $H^1$ norm.

Comment: @ChristianRemling but what is your argument that linear interpolation is the same as the piecewise constant one I am using?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the constant for the usual $L^{\infty}/H^1$ embedding will work for your $H^1_n$ norm also because that norm is the $H^1$ norm of the linearly interpolated function, and for the $L^{\infty}$ norm, it doesn't matter whether we interpolate linearly or piecewise constant.